# Validation Script trouble

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having some trouble with my validation script. It all looks good to me but now my validation column isn't loading. Here is the script...

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var datass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SG_Sheet1");

  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();

  if (activeCell.getColumn() == 1 && activeCell.getRow() > 1) {
    var makes = datass.getRange(2, 1, 1, datass.getLastColumn()).getValues();

    var makeIndex = makes[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 1;

    var validationRange = datass.getRange(3, makeIndex, datass.getLastRow());
    var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);
  }
}
```

So the issue is with my `ValidationRange` variable. If my range doesn't start on the first row then it doesn't work. But if I do have it in the first row it imports data I don't want into my column. Is there a way to make this script work or to hide the incorrect data?

Comment: Can you use the debugger located  in one of the menus, it has bug icon.. Set a breakpoint and run, it may ask you for dummy data.. May be you are referencing a wrong column or thinking it’s a column but it’s a row..

Comment: There is no error message and the code seems to run fine, when I look into the script and the execution transcript it's doing what it's supposed to but not showing the correct information in the worksheet

Comment: Note that your range variable includes 2 rows of blank values, because you started from row 3 and selected N rows from that point.

Comment: @tehhowch does that mean that I should be changing another piece of my code? or adding another "makes" variable with a different range to add to my data validation?

Comment: It means you need to use math to dynamically select only as many rows as will have data when you start with a different row than row 1.

Comment: `not showing the correct information in the worksheet` What exactly do you expect to show? Have you tried entering values out of the range?

Comment: @I'-'I I have a source worksheet that I'm pulling my data from. The first range (from my 'Makes' variable) is my index. Which starts on row 2 (there is information above in row 1 but nothing I want to move over to my validation worksheet) The second range (from my 'validationRange' Variable) is supposed to use the index and look into the 3rd row and pull the information that is there. It then creates a dropdown list in my validation worksheet. What I'm trying to do is keep excess information from the first 2 rows out of my dropdown list.

Comment: I understand all that. What I'm saying is that the data validation is successfully set.. What makes you say otherwise?

Comment: @I'-'I The dropdown list shows up just no values, i get a 'Loading...' note (because my source worksheet is from another workbook entirely). But i'll try adding the Boolean and see how that works.

Comment: @Hanna Just refresh and try again?  What does it show, when you go to DataValidation menu? Is the range set properly?

Comment: @I'-'I with the script above the menu is showing me that it's finding the right range and recognizing it but it wont show me the correct data just the 'loading' note

Comment: @Hanna Try waiting or refresh the page(Maybe a different browser)...Try  clicking loading again.  I don't think there's anything wrong with the code.

Comment: Provide a link to your spreadsheet, or a dummy spreadsheet if it contains 'private' information. It's very difficult to evaluate your code without knowing what the data looks like.

Comment: Here is the link. Thanks for the suggestion @Tedinoz.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CYxJidtHsQNfcuzSdwaq10l2JZkhEcWzufeeKzco9s8/edit?usp=sharing     This is a dummy sheet. And the only thing that differs is that I'm not using an app to connect the source data workbook to my price list. And this is also my original script that works (but includes the data I don't want) Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Sorry Hanna Logan. But that spreadsheet doesn't help at all. I haven't got the faintest idea what you are trying to do; the named sheet in the code doesn't appear in either sheet in the spreadsheet. There's discussion above of a dropdown, but that's not in the spreadsheet either. You've (understandably) disclosed more information to others, but the spreadsheet is totally unhelpful as a means of providing assistance.

Comment: @Tedinoz I just opened it and I'm not quite sure what you mean. I just opened the link again and it has everything In there. The dependent dropdown list is located in my 'Price list' sheet and the 'Source data' is my source.  I changed the names, because its a dummy sheet, but the code should reflect that. The only other difference then what we've been discussing above is that I in my dummy sheet I am not pulling any data from another workbook.

Comment: I added some more notes to the areas in hopes to clarify an confusion. I hope that will help

Comment: @HannaLogan Your model didn't display dropdowns (something about rights?). I've run your script in my own sheet (twice-different sheets, different accounts), and it works OK. I also added data validation to Prices Column A (picking up products from SourceData)-works too. When you update a value in Prices-Column A, "OnEdit" kicks in and put the new validation range in Column B. Only "unusual" thing is the validation range is SourceData A3:A6 - i.e. it includes a blank cell but perhaps that's just the test data. Happy to keep at this, but we have a 14 hour time difference.

Comment: @Tedinoz Thanks for trying this and for the help! (I don't mind the time difference if I can get this code right!) So the code runs for me as well if i Have this part of the code reading like so.....                                                                                    
   var validationRange = datass.getRange(1, makeIndex, datass.getLastRow());                                                                                               My issue isn't with the data validation (of Column A)or the dependent dropdown list that offsets into Column B.

Comment: The trouble I'm having is that my code doesn't work correctly if I try to start in Row 3. Row 3 to the last row (whichever that is as I add data) has the data that I want in my dropdown list in 'Prices' (Column B). the code I put above works but pulls the other data such as the Item name and anything else i put in Rows 1 and 2. I'm trying to eliminate that the "extra data" . Does that make sense?

Comment: @HannaLogan Time to look more closely at your code and check some of the values. The Logger entries in my Answer and my Code are deliberate to enable you to compare to your results. This ought to indicate exactly where your problem lies.

Answer (score 1):

The following code creates a dropdown list on the row adjacent to the active cell in the PriceList sheet.

The dropdown data comes from Sourcedata. Its interesting to note that the number of rows in the validation range is calculated as (three plus the last row of the SourceData).
[image: SourceData snapshot]
Based on this snapshot, the last row is 4. The validation range is declared as row=3, column=variable, lastrownumber=4. So if the item was "Pants", then the validation range "should" be Column=A StartRow=3; End Row=7(three plus four).However the range actually returned is A3:A6 (which generates one blank row, as expected). But it is one row short of the expected number of rows.

I created a data validation rule for Column A of the PriceList sheet. Clicking in a cell in this column triggers the "OnEdit" function which inserts the lookup in Column B.
[image: Screenshot PriceList sheet]

The following Logger entries show the various data elements for the most recent entry

```
[18-10-05 18:06:39:096 PDT] activeCell = A6    
[18-10-05 18:06:39:097 PDT] Active Row =6, Active Column = 1    
[18-10-05 18:06:39:210 PDT] value of the active cell = Pants    
[18-10-05 18:06:39:292 PDT] last row of the data sheet = 4    
[18-10-05 18:06:39:359 PDT] last column of the data sheet = 3    
[18-10-05 18:06:39:429 PDT] makesrange = A2:C2    
[18-10-05 18:06:39:550 PDT] makes = Pants,Tie,Basket    
[18-10-05 18:06:39:551 PDT] makeIndex = 1    
[18-10-05 18:06:39:621 PDT] valrange = A3:A6 being row=3, col=makeindex=1, number of rows=getLastRow=4    
[18-10-05 18:06:39:684 PDT] validationRange = A3:A6    
[18-10-05 18:06:39:691 PDT] validation rule applies to = B6
```

---

```
function onEdit() {

    // declare the sheets
    var s1 = "PriceList";
    var s2 = "SourceData";

    //declare the app and the sheets
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var pricess = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(s1);
    var datass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(s2);

    //declare the active cell (must be in the Prices Sheet)
    var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
    Logger.log("activeCell = " + activeCell.getA1Notation());

    // get the row and column of the active cell
    var SelectRow = activeCell.getRow();
    var SelectCol = activeCell.getColumn();
    Logger.log("Active Row =" + SelectRow + ", Active Column = " + SelectCol);

    // so if you are working on something in Column A and below row 1 (the header) t then do stuff
    if (activeCell.getColumn() == 1 && activeCell.getRow() > 1) {

        // Make a note of the content of the active cell
        Logger.log("value of the active cell = " + activeCell.getValue());

        //get the last row of data in the SourceData sheet
        var lastRow = datass.getLastRow();
        Logger.log("last row of the data sheet = " + lastRow);
        //get the last column in the SourceData sheet
        var lastColumn = datass.getLastColumn();
        Logger.log("last column of the data sheet = " + lastColumn);

        // declare (for reporting purposes) the 'makesrange' range (which maps to same address as "makes"
        // row = 2, column = 1(A), number of rows = 1 = row 2 only, number of columns = datass.getlastcolumn = 3 (Column C); so range = A2:C2
        var makesrange = datass.getRange(2, 1, 1, datass.getLastColumn()).getA1Notation();
        //(row 2, col 1) = A2, (num rows = 1, num cols = 3) = C2
        Logger.log("makesrange = " + makesrange);

        // declare (for calculation) the 'makes' range 
        // row = 2, column = 1(A), number of rows = 1 = row 2 only, number of columns = datass.getlastcolumn = 3 (Column C); so range = A2:C2
        var makes = datass.getRange(2, 1, 1, datass.getLastColumn()).getValues();
        //getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns) row 2, col 1, num rows=1, num cols=3
        Logger.log("makes = " + makes);

        // declare makeindex = converts the item selected on the Prices sheet to the relevant column on the SourceData sheet plus 1 (to account for array starting value=0) 
        var makeIndex = makes[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 1;
        Logger.log("makeIndex = " + makeIndex);

        // declaring (for reporting purposes) the 'valrange' which maps to the same address as "ValidationRange
        // row=3, c=makeindex==maps to column number contain product name the same as the active cell, last row of sourcedata
        var valrange = datass.getRange(3, makeIndex, datass.getLastRow()).getA1Notation();
        // row,col,number of rows ->row 3, col 1) = A3, (num rows = getlastrow=4) = ; so range = A3:C7, but returns as A3:C6???
        Logger.log("valrange = " + valrange + " being row=3, col=makeindex=" + makeIndex + ", number of rows=getLastRow=" + lastRow);

        // declare the "ValidationRange"
        // documentation says "When the "numRows" argument is used, only a single column of data is returned."
        //row=3, column=makeindex==maps to column number contain product name the same as the active cell, number of rows=last row# of sourcedata=4; so range = A2:C7, but returns as A3:C6???
        var validationRange = datass.getRange(3, makeIndex, datass.getLastRow());
        // row,col, number of rows ->row=3. col=makeindex=maps to column number contain product name the same as the active cell, 1 (=A), getLastRow
        Logger.log("validationRange = " + validationRange.getA1Notation()); // agrees to 'valrange'

        // declare validationrue = validationrule
        var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
        // apply the rule to the column B on PriceList(one to the right of Column A) and same row.
        activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);
        Logger.log("validation rule applies to = " + activeCell.offset(0, 1).getA1Notation());
    }
}
```

---

Comment: Thanks for the help @Tedinoz it worked so well! My sheets are a dream now! thank you!